# Yii foreach error?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have calling a function. get table number (result=0) results and updated same table value 0 to 1. i am using update query.i have run this function to return error :: Missing argument 2 for CDbCommand::update().

```
 public function newdisplaycontent()
{
    $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select()
        ->from('scrolltable')
        ->where('result=:result', array(':result'=>0))
        ->queryAll();
$rs=array();
//print_r($count);

foreach($count as $item){
//process each item here
    $rs=$item['ID'];
    $user=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update("scrolltable SET result = 1")
    ->where('ID=:id', array(':id'=>$rs));
}

return $rs;
}
```

thanks for your feature help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax of `update()` would be like below:

```
$user=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update("scrolltable",array("result" => "1"))
->where('ID=:id', array(':id'=>$rs));
```

As official document:

> `update()` Creates and executes an UPDATE SQL statement. The method will properly escape the column names and bind the values to be updated.

```
public integer update(string $table, array $columns, mixed $conditions='', array $params=array ( ))
```